# How to redirect user of one opencart site to another opencart site after login?

Tags: php, opencart, e-commerce, opencart-3

I have 2 websites of opencart. Now, I have to redirect customers of the one opencart site to another opencart site.

I have one website, Customer of that site will allow clicking on a button that button will redirect to another opencart site and get registered on that site. and then they will be able to order on the same site.

EX: https://example.com and another site is https://example2.com there is a button "send me to store" on https://example.com Now, when the customer clicks on that button it will redirect to https://example2.com site and get register to that site.

Anybody know how can it be possible please suggest me the proper way to do this kind of redirection in between two different opencart setups.it would be a great help.

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

Let me check if I got it clear and then offer my solution:

- So you want to have one customer be logged in (registered) in 2 different opencart sites?
- the customer should be able to order from both sites.

there are 2 possibilities:

1. the easy one: Set up multistore in OpenCart. Multistore feature allows you to have one OC installation with one database, one customer table and one order list for 2 different web domains.

to set up multistore, go to your opencart admin and select in left menu `system -> settings` and click the plus button on top right (create new store)

then add the domain name of the second store and other information. here is a youtube video you can follow https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xPexoqI4AMo

2. the hard one: if you do not want to use multistore, and would like to have two different OC installations, you will manually have to implement the logic for registering two accounts for one customer.

This would be possible if for example, you are hosting the two stores on one server, you would have access to both of the databases and just edit them with the same credentials when a user Creates/edits/deletes and account.

Another issue comes up with the SESSION. the session keeps the user logged in and it is attached to the domain name since it uses cookies to store the session id. if the users switch from one domain to the other, the cookies no longer know if this customer is logged in. so you will need to implement the logic for passing the session id to the other store when you redirect him.

I hope this gives you some understanding of you case.